# Javascript: error Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression no-unneeded-ternary

Tags: javascript, regex, email, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am new to javascript and I can't seem to wrap my head around a small issue I have. I looked everywhere, I tried many other options, but nothing seems to work.
This function works just fine, but I get this error message:

```
error  Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression  no-unneeded-ternary
```

Here is my code:

```
const valid = (email) => {
  // TODO: return true if the `email` string has the right pattern!
  const match = (email.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/) ? true : false);
  return match;
};
```

Anyone knows how I could write this differently? Thank you in advance for your help!
Olivier

Comment: the ternary casts it to a boolean. This is slower and more cognitively draining than just returning Boolean on the match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) which returns a boolean value.

```
const valid = email => /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/.test(email);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense. I came across this .test function but didn't really know how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`condition ? true : false;` is really weird

use `Boolean(condition)` or `!!condition`

to cast boolean type

```
const valid = (email) => {
    // TODO: return true if the `email` string has the right pattern!
    const match = email.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/);
    return Boolean(match);
};
```

Comment: this method will always return true, casting is not the issue here. String.prototype.match() returns an array

Comment: no @RobertMennell - returns `null` if no matches are found - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: ah good catch, I got a little confused on the empty call. Thanks for that

Comment: Thank you guys for addressing my issue, I appreciate. Another useful reply, it was tough deciding who to grant the official response.

Comment: @OlivierGirardot question subject was about wrong cast type to boolean, but definitely no cast is the best cast ;)